# What service has to be on in order for me to remote desktop into my machine?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-8.1

I have a new Windows 8.1 machine at work and for whatever reason I can't remote desktop into it.  It just says that Remote Access to the machine is not enabled.

I can connect to the machine via Computer Management.  What service do I need to enable in order to terminal into my box?

Comment: Maybe a silly question but not mentionned in a "what i've tried" section : have you enabled this feature using System Properties box via the Control Panel ?

Answer (score 0):

This powershell snip will turn on Remote Desktop in case it is disabled.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" -Name "fDenyTSConnections" -Value 0
#
```

This will start the service.

```
net start termservice
```

If you still cannot connect, uncheck the NLA box to allow sessions from lesser clients.

[image]

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for a registry setting to disable the NLA box, but for now just use the GUI.  EDIT: I guess is this  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d4feb20d-cb8b-4e49-8950-5e948e125414/network-level-authentication-error-with-remote-desktop-connection-between-windows-7-machines

Comment: I tried starting the service but it said that the service was already started.  I guess I'll have to check the computer tomorrow when i go back to work.